# Using sass in React as: import './App.scss';

Tags: javascript, sass, preact

I'm using preact-cli to generate projects and can modify webpack config.

I want to import styles into my components using the following format;

```
// Component.scss
.component {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
}


// Component.jsx
import './style.scss';

const Component = () => (
 <div className="component">
 </div>
)
export default Component
```

With component styled using the .scss styles...

Answer (score 0):

according to the [latest documentation](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli#sass) of preact-cli, you are supposed to run following command inside of your preact application folder :

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader
```

Edit:

I see what you are doing wrong. You have to use your styles like this :

**styles.scss**

```css
.test {
  background: red;
}
```

**header.js**

```js
import styles from "./style.scss";

const Header = () => (
  <header class={styles.test}>
    <h1>Preact App</h1>
    <nav />
  </header>
);

export default Header;
```

### Why You have to do it this way?

Because it's bundled. Each style will be translated to a unique name. For example `.test` will be `.test__SOmeThiNG`.

So there will be no problem with using the class name `.test` in any other component.

Think of it like a sandbox for your component.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I want to be able to load styles and have them mapped to the classnames of my components

Comment: I can import sass files fine, but for example if I do;

`
body{
 background: red;
}
.component{
 background:black;
}
`

.components' background will not be black

Comment: I just tried it; first I did `preact create default stackoverflow-test` then the npm install command in reply. changed `/src/routes/home.css` to `.scss`, changed import inside of `index.js` to `import "./style.scss"` (also ` import style from "./style.scss";` is working same way ). Then it's working. To add - I don't see the reason why some small child component has to change your body props. Every component has to care about itself. Not changing/mutating anything outside it :)

Comment: I just the updated answer, just seen what's the wrong part in your use sample.

Comment: You don't understand... I don't want to do that, I want to use my styles by using anonymous references.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to import css/scss files like that on my preact project on the components at `src/components`. It seems that imported css/scss files from `src/components` folder gets treated as CSS modules (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/931#issuecomment-605528374)) which could be used as in Filip Lintner's answer.

One solution is to customize preact-cli by creating a `preact.config.js` at your project root directory and mutate the original webpack config to disable bundling as CSS modules (where class names gets hashed). In my case, this is how I configured webpack in `preact.config.js` for disabling the hashing only (original 2-line config snippet from [here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/931#issuecomment-624258045)):

```
export default {
    webpack(config, env, helpers, options) {
        const [ css ] = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'css-loader');
        css.loader.options.modules = false;
    }
};
```

More info about customizing preact-cli: https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/#webpack